# How to get a QTextBlock's offset relative to the current document layout?

Tags: qt, coordinates, css, qplaintextedit

Given a text block, is there a way to determine its offset relative to the coordinates `(0, 0)` of the current document layout?

For example, suppose I have a `QPlainTextEdit` with the following contents:

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

If the height of each line is `17px`, how can I get the offset of line 2? Since line 1 is at the top, it should be `0px` from the top and line 2 should be `17px` from the top.

I tried a number of different functions but none of them seems to have the information:

- [`QPlainTextEdit::blockBoundingGeometry()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qplaintextedit.html#blockBoundingGeometry)
- [`QPlainTextEdit::blockBoundingRect()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qplaintextedit.html#blockBoundingRect)

None of these methods seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can try QTextCursor.

```
QTextEdit textEdit;
QTextCursor c =  textEdit->textCursor();
c.position();
```

or

```
c.positionInBlock();
```

Check documents on QTextCursor for details.